# How to change the default value of a property field in Odoo (old API)?

Tags: odoo

I'm trying to change the default value of some property fields such as: 'cost_method', 'product_type' and 'valuation' of the 'product' module but I can only change the non-property fields only.

What I tried:
- I created a new module and inherited the 'product.template' model and overridden the '_default' dictionary only but it didn't work.

- I created new fields with the same name but of another type (selection) not property but neither did this work.

The code:

```
 _name = "product.template"
 _inherit = "product.template"
```

_columns = {

'cost_method': fields.selection([('average', 'Average Price'),('standard', 'Standard Price'),  ('real', 'Real Price')])
        ,'type': fields.selection([('product', 'Stockable Product'),('consu', 'Consumable'),('service','Service')], 'Product Type', required=True, help="Consumable are product where you don't manage stock, a service is a non-material product provided by a company or an individual.")
 ,'company_id': fields.many2one('res.company', 'Company', required=False)
        }

```
 _defaults = {
    'company_id': False
    ,'type' : 'product'
    , 'cost_method': 'average'
    , 'barcode':'555'
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use only `_inherit="product.template"`. In your case you don't need the `_name` property.

Did you add your py. File to your `__init__.py`?

Did you set the correct dependencies in your `__openerp__.py`. In your case "product"?

Hope that helps you. Let me know.

**EDIT:**
I could reproduce your problem. My Code for testing

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from openerp.osv import osv, fields

class product_template(osv.osv):
    _name = "product.template"
    _inherit = "product.template"

    _columns = {
        'cost_method': fields.selection([('average', 'Average Price'),('standard', 'Standard Price'),('real', 'Real Price')]),
        'type': fields.selection([('product', 'Stockable Product'),('consu', 'Consumable'),('service','Service')],'Product Type', required=True, help="Consumable are product where you don't manage stock, a service is a non-material product provided by a company or an individual.") ,
        'company_id': fields.many2one('res.company', 'Company', required=False)
    }

    _defaults = {
        'company_id': False,
        'type' : 'consu',
        'cost_method': 'average',
        'barcode':'555'
    }
```

Here the `type`-field never had the `consu` value. In my case I could solve the problem by opening the menu `Settings -> Technical Settings ->  Actions -> User-defined Defaults`. I deleted all entries where the name is `type` and modelname is `product.template`.

Now if I create a new product the default type is `consu`. Same behaviour with `cost_method`-field.

Comment: I did all this. As I said before, my code works just fine except with the property fields. And it also works even with the property fields if I change their type to 'Char' for example. But when I change the type to 'Selection' Odoo keeps thinking they are property fields and tries to get their values from the 'ir_property' table and if I delete those values from the 'ir_property' table, Odoo puts blank values. The question now is: How to delete the old fields? or how to convince Odoo to take my defaults and not fetch them from the 'ir_property'?

Comment: Did you see my modification?

Comment: Worked with 'type' but not with 'cost_method. Very confusing!